# Page display after hitting back button

Tags: angularjs

I'm quite new to angular and i'm experiencing this apparently common issue for the first time. I've read around all the topic explaining it but there seems to be many different solutions / hacks and i would like to know what is good practice on the matter.

I have a simple , multi page app. Each page of the app got it's own path.But whenever i hit the back button the path change but ng-view become blank.
There is hardly any parameter in my url they are mostly simple pages and a couple of /show page 'content/:id'.
When i navigate to their own path individually they work but if i hit the back button , the path change in the browser and ng-view => blank.

There seems to be 2-3 ways of doing that that i found,

Either to store the path of the previous page every time the path is changed and creating a back button that would call a function that would change path to the previous url , which seems awful or reloading the whole page completely on path change when back button is hit which seems bad but not out of the question since it would be only when pressing back or to really be able to use the back button with the content already loaded inside my browser without having to recall the server which seems to be ideal but maybe there is a better way.

Could you explain me a way of doing that "the way to should be done", i don't really want to end up having a "back" link in my app.

I know you guys like code but i don't think there is a need here. Feel free to ask if you need it.

Some code :

```
    angular.module('TestTool',['ngRoute','ng-rails-csrf','ui.bootstrap','ngAnimate'])
    .config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider.when('/openquestions', {
        templateUrl: '/qa-index.html',
        controller:'QaController',
      })
      .when("/openquestions/:id", {
        templateUrl: '/qa-show.html',
        controller:'QaShowController',
      })
      .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });
```

-

```
  angular.module('TestTool')
  .controller('QaShowController',['$scope', '$http','$location','$routeParams', function($scope,$http,$location,$routeParams) {
   $http.get('/qaquestions/' + $routeParams.id + '.json').
      then(function(response) {
        $scope.test = " ok "
        $scope.Qdata = response.data;
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
      }, function(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
          $scope.test = " error"
    });
  }]);
```

-

```
    angular.module('TestTool')
    .controller('QaController',['$scope', '$http','$location', function($scope,$http,$location) {
    ////////////////////////////////////////////
      $http.get('/qaquestions.json').
        then(function(response) {
          $scope.test = " ok "
          $scope.List = response.data;
          // this callback will be called asynchronously
          // when the response is available
        }, function(response) {
          // called asynchronously if an error occurs
          // or server returns response with an error status.
            $scope.test = " error"
      });
      //todo $scope.vote = function(id){};
    /////////////// Show
      $scope.OpenQuestion = function(Id){
        var url = '/openquestions/'+ Id
        $location.path(url)
        $scope.$apply();
        };
    }]);
```

My view are useless i guess , but basically i'm going from my index to my show page using the OpenQuestion function.
It's just a sample of the code and it's not the whole app routing but that  part is behaving like the rest of the website.

Comment: The back button should work fine, out of the box. If it doesn't, then there is a problem in your code. Post a complete minimal example repproducing the problem.

Comment: I've updated the post

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1**

If you say your site is "multi-page", I assume your URL path will look like this:

`example.com/page1.html`

`example.com/page2.html`
...

You will need to setup a link to page2.html in page1.html, either through `$location` or anchor `tags`.

**Case 2**

If you mean your site is "multi-view", then the URL will be routed through Angular RouteProvider, like this:

`example.com/contact`

`example.com/product`

The back button should server your purpose.

**Case 3**

If you mean your site is just "single-view", but with multiple parameters, like this:

`example.com/contact/1`

`example.com/contact/2`

The back button should server your purpose.

Comment: It's a mix of 2 and 3 
I got example.com/#contacts
example.com/#products/
example.com/#product/1
example.com/#product/new
etc..

Comment: It should work if you set up the router correctly. Could you paste in your `$routeProvider` config code in your app.config?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code available, I will run through a simple MEAN stack routing architecture for you, pointing out common pitfalls.

First of all, you need the back and reload actions to appropriately route through angular, like normal get requests do. This is done in express using the following two lines.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app_client')));
app.use(function (req,res){
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, 'app_client', 'index.html'))
});
```

This will route all references to / (root) into the app_client folder, where (through index.html) angular will handle them in the appropriate way. Next, make sure **all your routes in ngRouter begin with /.** This is the most common issue with routing problems. If you have:

```
templateUrl: "home/homePage.html"
```

and you hit reload on the home page, angular will search for home/homePage.html **from the current directory, not the root directory**, so this needs to be:

```
templateUrl: "/home/homePage.html"
```

This architecture should enable express -> angular routing and allow the default cases of the back and reload buttons to work appropriately. No custom handlers are required for these simple actions.

Comment: I don't get how the backend is relevant ? and i don't mean that sarcastically , my back end is in Rails i'm getting my data as json , i didn't even thought the issue could come from that. Could it be a conflict between both router ?

Comment: The backend is relevant because that's where the GET request gets caught, and then your server routes the request into angular handlers. If this is malfunctioning it could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: but there shouldn't be any get request that triggers a route server side at all in my case(only the json data get request ) when backing it's all frontend, only the angular router should be used the way i made it

Comment: Any idea what could be causing the random blank pages on back ?

Comment: As posted in my answer, my best guess is that you are referencing your templates from the current directory, and not the root directory. All paths to your html templates should begin with /.

Comment: They are all like this "/template.html" :(. 
I've played around with it and leaving out the product/:id case it's works sometimes  but often end up failing. It's really strange, because in my console i can see the json call being made by the proper controller when the back button is hit, it's just that the view don't render somehow..

Comment: Perhaps if you're using $location you need to turn Html5mode on. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider